# How can I inverse this pattern in Java?

Tags: java

So I want to print this pattern:

```
******* 
****** 
***** 
**** 
*** 
**
*
```

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class DO
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

   final int BASE_SIZE = 8;

   for (int r = 0; r < BASE_SIZE; r++)
  {
   for (int c = 0; c < (r + 1); c++)
   {
      System.out.print("*");
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
 }
```

How can I inverse the pattern I'm currently printing so I can get the one I just showed you?

Comment: Your "code so far" isn't the exact inverse of the pattern you're trying to print. I think you're missing another line at the beginning with 8 asterisks, or else you need to set `BASE_SIZE` to 7. Some suggestions: 1) Find a better name for the class than `DO`. 2) Make `BASE_SIZE` a `private static final int` and move it out to class-level. 3) Name your loop variables something like `rowNumber` and `columnNumber` to make it immediately obvious what you're trying to do. 4) Get rid of the redundant `java.util.*` import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would implement it with a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Start with the longest line, and in a loop subtract one character until the `StringBuilder` is empty. Something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("*******");
while (sb.length() > 0) {
    System.out.println(sb);
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the outer loop, you only need to change the inner loop to :

```
for (int c = BASE_SIZE; c > r; c--)
```

So :

```
    for (int r = 0; r < BASE_SIZE; r++)
    {
        for (int c = BASE_SIZE; c > r; c--)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int c = r ; c > 0 ; c--)
    System.out.print("*");
```